# Back Button and Refresh with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, history

I need a solution for the page refresh and the back button when using AJAX.

I'm using simple javascript for the AJAX implementation.

If anybody could send a code snippet I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

essentially, you need to use & monitor the hash portion of the url...

```
http://.../path?parms#hashpart
```

Whan you change the hash, iirc window.location.hash , it won't reload the page, but your ajax can monitor, and respond to it.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using jQuery, there's [the history plugin](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html).

Comment: Nice answer, is it possible to do this same without the jquery?

Comment: Anything doable with jQuery is possible without, by looking through the plugin source you may be able to figure out what techniques they're using to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that I've used in some of my pages. Add this to pages that changes are made at.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     window.name = "reloader"; 
}
```

this triggers when you leave those pages. You can also trigger it if there were changes made. So that it won't unnecessarily reload the page that needs reloading.
Then on pages that you want to get reloaded on after a the browser "back" use.

```
if (window.name == "reloader") {
    window.name = "no";
    location.reload();
}
```

this will trigger a reload on the page you need reloading to.

Answer (score 0):

The onbeforeunload event can be useful to guard against refreshing but it fires if you navigate away or refresh. If you require that users login to the app you can always show a generic message advising against navigating away and refreshing. If users click your app log out button set a var to disable the warning. Could probably also make a 'Close' button that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PathJS](https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs) it does not require jQuery or any other additional lib.